# networkx: node spacing when plotting multipartite graph

Tags: python-3.x, plot, graph, nodes, networkx

I want to plot a multiparite graph using `networkx`. However, when adding more nodes, the plot becomes very crowdy. Is there a way to have more space between nodes and partitions?

Looking at the documentation of `multipartite_layout`, I couldn't find parameters for this.
Of course, one could create complicated formulas for the positions, but since the spacing of `multipartite_layout` already looks so good for small graphs, I was how to scale this to bigger graphs.

Has anyone an idea how to do this (efficiently)?

Sample code, generating a graph with three partitions:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx


# build graph:
G = nx.Graph()
for i in range (0,30):
    G.add_node(i,layer=0)
for i in range (30,50):
    G.add_node(i,layer=1)
    for j in range(0,30):
        G.add_edge(i,j)
G.add_node(100,layer=2)
G.add_edge(40,100)

# plot graph
pos = nx.multipartite_layout(G, subset_key="layer",)
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))
nx.draw(G, pos,with_labels=False)
plt.axis("equal")
plt.show()
```

The current, crowdy plot:

[image]

Comment: Try removing plt.axis('equal') - this worked for me in a similar example

Answer (score 0):

`nx.multipartite_layout` returns a dictionary with the following format: `{node: array([x, y])}`

I suggest you try `pos = {p:array_op(pos[p]) for p in pos}` where `array_op` is a function acting on the position of each node, `array([x, y])`.

In your case, I think a simple scaling along the x-axis suffice, i.e.

`array_op = lambda x, sx: np.array(x[0]*sx, x[1])`.

For visualization purpose I guess this should be equivalent with @JPM 's comment. However, this approach gives you the advantage of having the actual transformed position data.

In the end, if such uniform transformation does not satisfy your need, you can always manipulate the position manually with the knowledge of the format of the dict (although it might be less efficient).